# auto-close flash with embed html5 tag?

Tags: html, flash, embed

I just found out about the embed tag for HTML5, and I would like to use it.

```
<embed src="example.swf" />
```

However, I haven't found thorough tutorials about the subject... or maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

My first question, since it looks this is a quite simple tag...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp

http://www.w3resource.com/html5/embed-element.php

... is how to get the flash to autoclose when it's finished played? or is that the expected behaviour of this tag?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for including swfs in html is to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) - its a javascript library (it does use embed).

There's no way to get flash to auto-close when its finished playing - it can be done manually, but you would need to amend the swf to call a javascript function when it has finished - then close or hide the flash content within the javascript function.